# Php mysql is returning only the last row when i use the auto refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I have the mysqli query which is returning only last record's value with all rows when i use the auto refresh with **below code** if i dont use the auto refresh then it works fine. Only problem I am facing when i use the auto refresh.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  refreshTable();
});

function refreshTable(){
    $('.tableHolder').load('itemtotal_cart_checkout.php', function(){
       setTimeout(refreshTable, 1000);
    });
}
```

How can i fix that please help.

```
$ses_mem    =   $_SESSION['ses_user_id'];
$getItem    =   $_GET['item_id'];

$order_temp =   "select * from temp_cart where item_id='".$getItem."' AND ses_mem='".$ses_mem."' order by id";
$tordera = $db->query($order_temp);
$torder = $tordera -> fetch_assoc();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP code expects `item_id` GET parameter. So you should pass it from JavaScript:

```
$('.tableHolder').load('itemtotal_cart_checkout.php?item_id=' + itemId,
  function(){
     setTimeout(refreshTable, 1000);
  });
```

Here's how you can get `item_id` from the current query string in JavaScript:

```
var m = location.search.match(/^.*[\?&]item_id\=(\d+)/);
var itemId = m && m.length >= 2 ? m[1] : 0;
```

If, however, the current page is a mixture of PHP and HTML with the JavaScript mentioned above, then just embed PHP into JavaScript:

```
<script>
/* skipped original code */
$('.tableHolder').load('itemtotal_cart_checkout.php?item_id=' + <?php
  echo isset($_GET['item_id']) ? (int) $_GET['item_id'] : 0;
?>,
  function(){
     setTimeout(refreshTable, 1000);
  });
/* skipped original code */
</script>
```

Finally, if the JavaScript is executed in a separate file, then you need a JavaScript function with an argument for item ID. For instance, in some *script.js* you might have a function similar to the following:

```
function refreshTable(itemId) {
    $('.tableHolder').load('itemtotal_cart_checkout.php?item_id=' + itemId, function() {
       setTimeout(function () { refreshTable(itemId) }, 1000);
    });
}
```

Then you can call it from PHP this way:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  refreshTable(<?php echo isset($_GET['item_id']) ? (int) $_GET['item_id'] : 0; ?>);
});
</script>
```

You might want to use `setInterval` instead of recursive calls to `setTimeout`, by the way.

Comment: i want to make item_id in Javascript as `?item_id=<?php echo $row_id; ?>` and get it in **itemtotal_cart_checkout.php**

Comment: @FahadAlmehaini, then you need to pass `$_GET['item_id']` to JavaScript code. If the JavaScript code is embedded into a PHP script (if the current page is a mixture of PHP, HTML and JavaScript), then just `load('itemtotal_cart_checkout.php?item_id=' + <?php echo $_GET['item_id']; ?> ...`

Comment: can you please adjust the code according to it please. Sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

Pass `item_id` variable to php by this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  refreshTable();
});

function refreshTable(){
    $('.tableHolder').load('itemtotal_cart_checkout.php<?php echo '?item_id=1'; ?>', function(){
       setTimeout(refreshTable, 1000);
    });
}
```